# VTK installation error in ubuntu

Tags: installation, vtk

I'm getting this error when I try to install VTK.

**CMake Error at CMake/ExternalData.cmake:1005 (message):
  Object MD5=66006f09007bd56bde48a899d4cebd47 not found at:
http://midas3.kitware.com/midas/api/rest?method=midas.bitstream.download&checksum=66006f09007bd56bde48a899d4cebd47&algorithm=MD5 (wrong hash MD5=a0a85923331d4faa2ba6ff130a19d946)
    http://www.vtk.org/files/ExternalData/MD5/66006f09007bd56bde48a899d4cebd47 ("Timeout was reached")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMake/ExternalData.cmake:1027 (_ExternalData_download_object)
CMakeFiles/VTKData.dir/build.make:8742: recipe for target 'ExternalData/Domains/Chemistry/Testing/Data/Baseline/TestVASPAnimationReader.png.md5-stamp' failed
make[2]:**  [ExternalData/Domains/Chemistry/Testing/Data/Baseline/TestVASPAnimationReader.png.md5-stamp] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/VTKData.dir/all' failed
make[1]:  **[CMakeFiles/VTKData.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2**

Here's what I did:

I unzipped my VTK downloaded files into a folder `VTK`

```
cd VTK
ccmake .
```

After configuring and generating in `ccmake`

```
make
```

The command executes for a while and then the above error shows. How do I fix this?